# Changing Lens metrics time period

Tags: kubernetes

We are using Lens for developing on Kubernetes and we have started using Lens Metrics Stack. Is there a way to change time period of visualization? It is set to `-60m` by default and so far we could not find any way to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. 60 minutes is the default, according to the information from [lensapp/lens GitHub repository](https://github.com/lensapp/lens/blob/58a446bd45f9ef21fe633e5cda1c695113d5b5c4/src/common/k8s-api/endpoints/metrics.api.ts#L55):

> time-range in seconds for data aggregation (default: 3600s = last 1h)

and there is no way to change this default value directly from the lens app.

I found a mention  for an [improvement of that behavior](https://github.com/lensapp/lens/issues/428):

> Metrics history beyond 1h #428

But at the moment it is still in Open status.